# Remove mutiple values from a hash in perl

Tags: perl

I need to iterate through a hash in perl and then if for a key multiple values are present in the form of an array , take the first value. My code snippet for that is

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%ARGS)) {
    print "$key-----------------------------$value\n\n";
    if ($key =~ /submit\.([\w-]+)/) {
        $submitField = $1;
    } elsif  ($key =~ /action/) {
        $submitField = $value;
    }
    if (ref($value) ) {
        if (%min_args)
        {
            print ("min args not found aborting the request");
            $m->comp('/x-locale/errors/404.m');
            $m->abort();
        }
        print "multiple value found for $key";
        $value = shift @$value if ref($value) eq "ARRAY";
        $ARGS{$key} = $value;
        print "value changed $ARGS{$key}\n\n";
        print Data::Dumper->Dump([$value]);
        print "<pre>" . Data::Dumper->Dump([%ARGS]) . "</pre>";
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I pass in more than one key having an array of values , its doing the shift operation only for the first one and coming out of the loop. Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: you don't show the end of the loop, or even the end of the `if (ref...`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not demonstrated a problem, and with the missing bits added, we get the expected result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %ARGS = (
   a => 'b',
   c => [ 'd', 'e' ],
   f => [ 'g', 'h' ],
   i => 'j',
);

while (my ($key, $value) = each(%ARGS)) {
# print "$key-----------------------------$value\n\n";
# if ($key =~ /submit\.([\w-]+)/) {
#    $submitField = $1;
# } elsif  ($key =~ /action/) {
#    $submitField = $value;
# }
 if (ref($value) ) {
#    if (%min_args) {
#       print ("min args not found aborting the request");
#       $m->comp('/x-locale/errors/404.m');
#       $m->abort();
#    }
#   print "multiple value found for $key";
   $value = shift @$value if ref($value) eq "ARRAY";
   $ARGS{$key} = $value;
#   print "value changed $ARGS{$key}\n\n";
#   print Data::Dumper->Dump([$value]);
#   print "<pre>" . Data::Dumper->Dump([%ARGS]) . "</pre>";
Data::Dumper->Dump([%ARGS]);
 }
}

print Dumper(\%ARGS);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => 'd',
          'a' => 'b',
          'f' => 'g',
          'i' => 'j'
        };
```

Mind you, there's some funky stuff going on. Each hash has only one iterator, so the Data::Dumper call inside the loop only sees part of the hash. It also resets the iterator, causing the `each` to restart. To avoid visiting the same keys repeatedly, move the call to Data::Dumper outside of the loop (where it should be) or use `for keys` instead of `while each` to gets all the keys upfront.